# Is it possible to dynamically point which Cuda 3DSurface use

Tags: cuda

The project concerns fluid simulation which is simulated using 3D grid (stencil simulation).

In each step I am reading values from one surface, computing and saving to second surface. The thing is that in each step the pointer to surfaces need to be swapped (in first iteration I want to Read from 1-st surface, write to 2nd, in second iteration I want to read from 2nd surface, write to 1st and so on). Is it possible to do it in a dynamic way? Now I am using some if-clause.

For example if it was 2D simulation I could use 2DlayeredSurface with two layers and there I could point which surface to use, but unfortunately 3DlayeredSurface does not exist.

Is it possible to create an array of  type and then point it by index ?

Comment: Can't you just bind each surface to the reference used in the kernel at each iteration?

Comment: From programming guide. " A surface reference can only be declared as a static global variable and cannot be passed as an argument to a function"

Comment: Yes, so you *bind* the data you want to the statically declared surface reference. Bind a different data array to the surface reference for each kernel call.

Comment: So if for example Surf1 is bind to cuArray1 and surf2 to cuArray2 and I want to swap it just write cudaBindSurfaceToArray(SurfRef_1, inArray2, channelDesc); cudaBindSurfaceToArray(SurfRef_2, inArray1, channelDesc)? I hope it is not any particularly slow ?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do it the way you describe, but for the small number of instructions you are talking about, predication works great.  Bind both surfaces, then you write if statements to determine which surface to read/write.  The compiler will issue predicated instructions and only one will be active.

A similar strategy is used to reference >2^27 texture elements (by predicating reads from up to 4 textures) in this file: https://github.com/ArchaeaSoftware/cudahandbook/blob/master/texturing/tex1dfetch_big.cu

Comment: Nop, it works the way i described it : cudaBindSurfaceToArray(SurfRef_1, inArray2, channelDesc) and so on